# You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.config()

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

i am getting the following error in android after adding notifications to the app.
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.config().

Ensure you have:

1) Installed the required Firebase Android SDK dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config' in your 'android/app/build.gradle' file.

2) Imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.config.RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

3) Added the 'new RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

when i do all the recommended things (com.google.firebase:firebase-notifications:16.0.0) i am getting
that the firebase-notifications:16.0.0 is not found error while running

Comment: Can you update your question with `build.gradle`, `MainApplication.java` and full error?

Comment: i solved the problem